# Creating a new column based on values from another field-same table

Tags: sql-server

How do you take this case statement and insert it into a complex query that's doing alot of left joins? I want to do exactly what this does--but I can't figure out where to add it in my query.

```sql
Select
    CASE
        WHEN [Activity Type] = 'A' THEN
            CASE WHEN MonitorA_ID is NULL
              OR MonitorA_Date is NULL
              OR MonitorA_Region is NULL
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    END as 'A_Chk'

From Table
```

where I thought I could do it, won't work-

```sql
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LABEL] LABEL on ISSUE = ji.id --1:M (possible) for each issue 
 --Custom Fields: Story Points
```

### let me know if more of the query is needed.

added full query:

```
select
 
pt.pname as project
, pt.pkey  as projectkey
, ji.issuenum
, ji.assignee
, ji.creator
,un.lower_user_name as updated_creator
,un_1.lower_user_name as updated_assignee
,un_2.lower_user_name as updated_reporter
, ji.reporter
, p.pname as Priority
, it.pname as Type
, iss.pname as Status
, r.pname as Resolution
, ji.summary
, ji.created
, ji.updated
, ji.duedate
, ji.resolutiondate
, cfo1.customvalue as Team
, cfo2.customvalue as impact
, cfo3.customvalue as found
, cfo4.customvalue as environment
,cfo5.name as sprint
, cfv6.stringvalue as remedyticket
, cfv7.stringvalue as apmId 
--, cf.CUSTOMFIELD
, pv1.vname as issuefixverion
, pv1.released as issuefixversionreleasestatus
, pv1.releasedate as issuefixversionreleasedate
, pv1.sequence as issuefixversionsequence
, pv2.vname as issueversion
, pv2.released as issueversionreleasestatus
, pv2.releasedate as issueversionreleasedate
, c3.cname as Delivery_Platform
,CF.[CUSTOMFIELD] as STORY_PNT_CSTM_FLD_ID
,CF.[NUMBERVALUE] as STORY_POINTS
,LABEL.[LABEL] as Label--will have multiple records per issue if more than 1 label is assigned
,ji.[ID] as ISSUE_ID_NUM
,ji.[Archived]
, cfv.STRINGVALUE
, cfv.ISSUE as ISUUEIdNum
, cfo.customvalue
, cfo.ID as IDCFO
, cf1.ID as IDCF
,datediff(hour,ji.[CREATED],ji.[RESOLUTIONDATE]) as 'Hours Impacted'
,datediff(hour,ji.[CREATED],ji.[RESOLUTIONDATE]) /24 as 'Days per Ticket'
,avg(datediff(day, ji.[CREATED],  ji.[RESOLUTIONDATE])) as 'Avg Age'
 
from [dbo].[jiraissue] ji
inner join [dbo].[issuetype] it on it.id = ji.issuetype
inner join [dbo].[project] pt on pt.id = ji.project
inner join [dbo].[issuestatus] iss on iss.id = ji.issuestatus
left join [dbo].[app_user] un on ji.creator=un.user_key 
left join [dbo].[app_user] un_1 on ji.assignee=un_1.user_key 
left join [dbo].[app_user] un_2 on ji.REPORTER=un_2.user_key 
 
left join [dbo].resolution r on r.id = ji.resolution
left join [dbo].[priority] p on p.sequence = ji.priority
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LABEL] LABEL on ISSUE = ji.id --1:M (possible) for each issue 
 --Custom Fields: Story Points
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[customfieldvalue] CF on CF.[ISSUE] = issuenum AND CF.CUSTOMFIELD = ' ' --Story Points Field
Left join [dbo].[customfieldvalue] cfv1
   on cfv1.issue =ji.id
   and  cfv1.customfield = ( select id from customfield where cfname =  'team ( ')
left join [dbo].[customfieldoption] cfo1  on cast(cfo1.id as varchar) = cfv1.stringvalue
 
left join [dbo].[customfieldvalue] cfv2
    on cfv2.issue =ji.id
    and  cfv2.customfield = ( select id from customfield where cfname =  'impact ( ')
left join [dbo].[customfieldoption] cfo2 on cast(cfo2.id as varchar) = cfv2.stringvalue
 
left join [dbo].[customfieldvalue] cfv3 on
    cfv3.issue =ji.id
    and  cfv3.customfield = ( select id from customfield where cfname =  'found ( ')
left join [dbo].[customfieldoption] cfo3 on cast(cfo3.id as varchar) = cfv3.stringvalue
 
left join [dbo].[customfieldvalue] cfv4
    on cfv4.issue =ji.id
    and  cfv4.customfield = ( select id from customfield where cfname =  'environment ( ')
left join [dbo].[customfieldoption] cfo4 on cast(cfo4.id as varchar) = cfv4.stringvalue
 
left join [dbo].[customfieldvalue] cfv5
    on cfv5.issue =ji.id
    and  cfv5.customfield = ( select id from customfield where cfname =  'sprint')
left join [dbo].[ao_60db71_sprint] cfo5 on cast(cfo5.id as varchar) = cfv5.stringvalue
 
left join [dbo].[customfieldvalue] cfv6
    on cfv6.issue =ji.id
    and  cfv6.customfield = ( select id from customfield where cfname =  'remedy ticket')
 
left join [dbo].[customfieldvalue] cfv7
   on cfv7.issue =ji.id
   and  cfv7.customfield = ( select id from customfield where cfname =  'APM ID')
 
left join customfieldvalue cfv on ji.id = cfv.issue  -- joins table 1 to table 2 based on jira id
LEFT JOIN customfieldoption cfo on cfv.stringvalue = (cast(cfo.id as varchar))   -- joins table 2 to table 3 based on stringvalue ( )
Left Join customfield cf1 on cfv.stringvalue = (cast(cf.id as varchar))  -- joins table 2 to table 4 based on stringvalue ( )
 
 
left join [dbo].nodeassociation na1 on na1.source_node_id = ji.id and na1.association_type ='issuefixversion'
left join [dbo].projectversion pv1 on pv1.id = na1.sink_node_id
 
left join [dbo].nodeassociation na2 on na2.source_node_id = ji.id and na2.association_type ='issueversion'
left join [dbo].projectversion pv2 on pv2.id = na2.sink_node_id
 
left join [dbo].nodeassociation na3  on na3.source_node_id = ji.id and na3.association_type ='issuecomponent'
left join dbo.[component] c3  on c3.id = na3.sink_node_id
 
where pt.pkey = ' ' OR
pt.pkey = ' '
and ji.archived='N'
group by pt.pname
, pt.pkey 
, ji.issuenum
, ji.assignee
, ji.creator
,un.lower_user_name 
,un_1.lower_user_name
,un_2.lower_user_name
, ji.reporter
, p.pname 
, it.pname 
, iss.pname 
, r.pname 
, ji.summary
, ji.created
, ji.updated
, ji.duedate
, ji.resolutiondate
, cfo1.customvalue 
, cfo2.customvalue 
, cfo3.customvalue 
, cfo4.customvalue 
, cfo5.name 
, cfv6.stringvalue 
, cfv7.stringvalue  
, pv1.vname 
, pv1.released 
, pv1.releasedate 
, pv1.sequence 
, pv2.vname 
, pv2.released 
, pv2.releasedate 
, c3.cname 
,CF.[CUSTOMFIELD]
,CF.[NUMBERVALUE] 
,LABEL.[LABEL]
,ji.[ID]
,ji.archived
, cfv.STRINGVALUE
, cfv.ISSUE
, cfo.customvalue
, cfo.ID
, cf1.ID
```

Comment: I don't follow what you are asking here. if you want that `CASE` **expression** in a different `SELECT`, just copy and paste it into the other `SELECT`. The only thing you will likely need to (should) do is qualify your column names (and not use literal strings for aliases). The fact that the other query has `LEFT JOIN`s is irrelevant.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help

Comment: What does `won't work` means? Can you show that complete query